# Unable to use precedent function output as an input for the next function in scraping web content

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I have 2 functions, called GetItemIDlist (to scrape all idproduct of a shop on ecommerce site) and GetID_image (to get image gallary (about 8 images per product item) and store locally)

Both of them works smoothly when run individually.

But I do not know how to use the output of function 1, which gives a list of product IDs shown below, as an input for the looping process in function 2.

Because Function 2, currently, has just been able to get image gallary if giving it an specific product id.

So, I want to add a loop (using an output list generated by function 1) to get all image gallary of all product items, not by mannually keying an item id into function 2.

Output of function 1:

```
1242118776
1379832161
2055592163
bla bla
1230767270
```

Function 1's script:

```
def GetItemIDList (shopid):
    i=0
    while i<20:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5',
            'Referer': 'myrefererurl'
        }
        url = 'myAPIurl_pre'+str(shopid)+'myAPIurl_end'  
        r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout= 5).json()
        for item in r['items']:
            itemid_list=item['itemid']
            print(itemid_list)
        i=i+1
```

Function 2 script:

```
def GetID_Image(item_id):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5',
        'Referer': 'myrefererheader'
    }   
    url = 'pre_myurl'+item_id+'end_myurl'
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout= 5).json()
    itemid_shop=r['item']['itemid']
    itemname_shop=r['item']['name']
    print(itemname_shop)
    itemimage_shop=r['item']['images']
    endtag_image=range (11) #range(len(list(itemimage_shop))
    for imageid,i in zip(itemimage_shop,endtag_image):
        image_fronturl="myfronturl"
        image_fullurl=image_fronturl+imageid
        myfile = requests.get(image_fullurl, allow_redirects=True)
        open('mylocalfolder'+itemname_shop+'_'+str(i)+'.jpg', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

Pls take time to help me in this case, thanks so much!

Comment: Notice that your first function `GetItemIDList` does not return anything. So it can't feed your second function with inputs...

Comment: Consider adding `return itemid_list` in your first function.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all `get_items` returns list of available items id (20 items) in a specific shop (using `shop_id`)

```py
def get_items(shop_id):
    item_list = []
    for _ in range(20):
        resp = requests.get(
            url='my_api_url_pre/{}/my_api_url_end'.format(shopid)
            headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5',
                'Referer': 'myrefererurl'
            },
            timeout= 5
        ).json()

        items = resp['items']
        for item in items:
            item_list.append(item['itemid'])

    return item_list
```

then `save_images` store all images available for an item (using `item_id`) locally.

```py
def save_images(item_id):   
    resp = requests.get(
        url='pre_my_url/{}/end_my_url'.format(item_id),
        headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5',
            'Referer': 'myrefererheader'
        },
        timeout=5
    ).json()

    item = resp['item']
    shop_id, shop_name = item['itemid'], item['name']
    shop_images = item['images']

    for i, image_id in enumerate(shop_images):
        image = requests.get(
            url='my_front_url/{}'.format(image_id),
            allow_redirects=True
        )
        filename = '{my_local_folder}/{}_{}.jpg', shop_name, i)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file
            file.write(image.content)
```

and finally try to loops over the list of items in a shop and store their images locally.

```py
item_list = get_products(SOME_SHOP_ID)

for item_id in item_list:
    save_images(item_id)
```